# Квадратные скобки в HTML

Tags: html, браузер

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Пишу на Блогере статью. Пишу, находясь не в *Создать*, а в *HTML*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
. Нужно вставить такую строку:

```
triple[nbpts]
```

чтобы было в одну строку и с квадратными, а получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, плиз, как сделать? Думал, это как-то с экранированием связано, но, по ходу, не в ту степь.

---

Давайте я попробую здесь сделать в Хроме, а результат посмотреть в IE:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"] }});
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    processEscapes: true
  }
});
</script>

<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
$x_{1,\,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ что-то написано [nbpts]
```

Я думал, дело в подключении mathjax и брвузере IE, однако в IE вижу следующее:
[image]
Остается одно различие в просмотрах здесь и на блоге - в используемых для этого движках.

Comment: _Пишу, находясь не в Создать, а в HTML_ ?????

Comment: Балин, фотку нужно, опять ерунда получится.

Comment: думаю проблема в движке блога, где вы пишите и не совсем понятно, какой ответ вы хотите получить

Comment: Уточнил стартовый пост.

Comment: Ну и что за движок-то?

Comment: А где это узнать? Я просто зарегистрировался на https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/ и начал писать, ничего не изменив принципиально в настройках. Подцепил еще http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathjax.html

Answer (score 2):

Все, нашел я решение [здесь](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/html.html#html-special-characters). Проблему решает вот это:

```
<span>[</span>
```

и это

```
<span>]</span>
```

Всем спасибо за попытку помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте коды символов

**[** (Квадратная скобка открывающая) - `&#91;`
**]** (Квадратная скобка закрывающая) - `&#93;`

Или экранируйте символы обратным слешем **`\`**.

```html
triple&#91;nbpts&#93;
```

Comment: Про коды скобок знаю, пробовал. Получалось так: https://postimg.cc/NLj7g646. Экранирование же символов обратным слешем \ приведет к тому, что подклеченный mathjax станет считать это выклочной формулой. У меня, честно говоря, создалось впечатление, что именно поэтому так и получается.